# How do you make elements scale down based on display size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making a website for school.
luke18f.github.io
I've pretty much finished but one problem is that when the display size narrows the twitter feed covers up the countdown table.

How would I make it so my website is displayed properly for any display size?

```js
// data is an array of objects, each representing one of your categories.
// Each category has a .title to store its title and a .counters that
// stores an object for each counter in that category.
var data = [
    {
  title: 'LEAGUES',
  counters: [
    // Each counter has a .title and a .date that is parsed by new Date()
    {
      title: 'IPL',
      date: 'September 19, 2020'
    },
    {
      title: 'BBL',
      date: 'December 3, 2020'
    },
    
  ]
    },
    {
  title: 'ICC TOURNAMENTS',
    counters: [
      {
        title: "Men's T20 World Cup (Postponed)",
        date: "October 18, 2020"
      },
      {
        title: "Women's Cricket World Cup (Postponed)",
        date: 'February 6, 2021'
      },
      
      
    ]
  },
  {
  title: 'INTERNATIONAL SERIES',
     counters: [
      {
        title: "Australia tour of England",
        date: 'September 4, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "West Indies tour of Australia (Postponed)",
        date: 'October 4, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "India tour of Australia",
        date: 'October 11, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "Afghanistan tour of Australia",
        date: "November 21, 2020"
      },
      {
        title: "New Zealand tour of Australia",
        date: "January 26, 2021"
      },
     
  ]
  },
]
    
  
  // this reduce generates the table
  let table = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc + `<tr><td colspan="6" class="category">${category.title}</td></tr>` +
  category.counters.reduce((acc, counter, index) => {
    return acc + `<tr id="counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}">
    <td>${counter.title}</td>
    <td>${counter.date}</td>
    <td class="days"></td>
    <td class="hours"></td>
    <td class="minutes"></td>
    <td class="seconds"></td>
    </tr>`;
    }, '');
  }, '<table class="countdown"><tr><th>Event</th><th>Date</th><th>Days</th><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th><th>Seconds</th></tr>');
  table += '</table>';
  
  // insert the table after the noscript tag
  document.getElementById('countdown').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', table);
  
  // generate a flat list of counters
  let counters = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc.concat(category.counters.reduce((counterAcc, counter, index) => {
      return counterAcc.concat([{
        // counters will be an array of the objects we generate here.
        // node contains a reference to the tr element for this counter
        node: document.getElementById(`counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}`),
        // date is the date for this counter parsed by Date and then converted
        // into a timestamp
        date: (new Date(counter.date)).getTime()
        }]);
      }, []));
  }, []);
  // calculates time
  const msSecond = 1000,
    msMinute = msSecond * 60,
    msHour = msMinute * 60,
    msDay = msHour * 24;
  let intervalId;
  
  function updateCounters () {
    counters.forEach((counter, counterIndex) => {
    let remaining = counter.date - Date.now(),
      node = counter.node;
    let setText = (selector, text) => node.querySelector(selector).textContent = text;
  
    if (remaining > 0) {
      setText('.days', Math.floor(remaining / msDay));
      remaining %= msDay;
      setText('.hours', Math.floor(remaining / msHour));
      remaining %= msHour;
      setText('.minutes', Math.floor(remaining / msMinute));
      remaining %= msMinute;
      setText('.seconds', Math.floor(remaining / msSecond));
    } else {
      // make sure I don't accidentally display negative numbers if a timer
      // firing late returns a past timestamp (or the data contains a past date)
      setText('.days', 0);
      setText('.hours', 0);
      setText('.minutes', 0);
      setText('.seconds', 0);
  
      // This countdown has reached 0 seconds, stop updating it.
      counters.splice(counterIndex, 1);
      // no more counters? Stop the timer
      if (counters.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
    });
  }
  // display counters right away without waiting a second
  updateCounters();
  intervalId = setInterval(updateCounters, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

div.title 
{
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}
div.cricket-ball
{
    text-align: right;
    contain: content;
}
link
{
    color: white;
}
div.calendar-download{
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      
      a:hover, a:active {
        background-color: red;
      }
script {
    display: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf;
}
.category {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
td, th {
    padding: .5em;
}
.days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
    text-align: right;
}
#countdown thead tr
{
    background-color: crimson;
}
#image
{
   text-align: right; 
   object-fit: cover;
   padding: 0px;
}
a.twitter-timeline
{
    text-align: right;
    height: fit-content;
}
.twitter  {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
}
.table {
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
}
div.footer
{
    display: flexbox;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
a
{
    display: inline-block;
}
img.w3-schools
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 175px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
    <head>
        <title>CCC</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cccstyle.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+De+Haviland&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--top of the page title--> 
        <div class="title">
            <h1>The CCC</h1>
            <h3>Comprehensive Cricket Countdown</h3>
        </div class="title">
        <div class="calendar-download"> <!--this is the calendar download button which downloads the .ics file-->
            <a href="C:\Users\lukef\Desktop\Website\Comprehensive Cricket Countdown\media\Comprehensive_Cricket_Countdown.ics" download>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IFtJfeb.png" alt="Add to calendar" height="30" width="150">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="twitter" align = "right">
            <!--This is the twitter timeline aligned to the right of the website-->
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="400" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/ICC?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by ICC</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>
        
        <noscript id="countdown">Sorry, you need JavaScript enabled to view the count
            downs</noscript>

             
        <div class="table">
        <script src="table.js"></script>
        <!--This is the link to the javascript that powers the countdown table-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="footer">
        <!--red background saying thank-you to these websites that helped me with clickable icons-->
      <h1>Special thanks to:</h1>
      <p>
        <a href="https://www.cricbuzz.com" target="blank">
        <img border="0" alt="CricBuzz" src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="151" height="85">
        </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="https://w3schools.com" target="blank">
            <img class="w3-schools" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i-ij7KM2pFUUpFE31QAUDXg5mzGFNbm16S4tjmg2ZyuhCGLgNJ8oXJRbq7ysh6LoZg" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This text is here because I don't know if I can add any more details but the website wants me too so please ignore this feeble solution.

Comment: Other details you could add include a screenshot, a description of what exactly it's _supposed_ to look like...

Comment: Educate yourself on *CSS media queries*.

Comment: You can scale in CSS based on screen size using vw, vh, vmin, vmax https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp
You can change layouts based on screen breakpoints using CSS media queries. You can also use CSS grid to change layouts based on available space using fixed size grid cells.

Answer (score 0):

As per the standard, to make HTML work in `fixed sized` outputs with pre-defined standard sizes, you need to use Media Query or Responsive CSS libraries

Below is the documentation from [Mozilla developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

> Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or browser viewport width).

To make you life easy, you can choose libraries like Bootstrap which already has CSS designed to do this kind RWD (Responsive Web Design )

[Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Documentation from Bootstrap

> Quickly design and customize responsive mobile-first sites with Bootstrap, the world’s most popular front-end open source toolkit, featuring Sass variables and mixins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt components, and powerful JavaScript plugins.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first the `meta="viewport"` which enable the content to be scale properly to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

> A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:
> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
> a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
> device-width, which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
> scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
> values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
> or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is
> first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable
> properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

Source @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

```
.twitter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
}
```

By using postion absolute you wont be abble to properly adapt the desing with your twitter feed to mobile.

You should take a look ay grids system https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp to get an adpative design.

Using frameworks is a good idea but you might have some restriction in regards to your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue by removing the absolute position of the twitter container and instead use a flex on a parent container (`content` in this case) that automatically wraps the table and the twitter feed if the screen size is too small. So the twitter feed will appear under the table on smaller screens; I think this is the proper design solution rather than compressing the table.

I also updated your title and footer divs to proper HTML semantics (header, footer), and I guessed that you wanted no spacing around your header and footer, which made me add 0px to the body's padding and margin.

I finally updated your code and simplified it slightly by adding a `<table id="countdown">` to the HTML straight away.

---

I highly suggest that you refactor your code. Each functionality that is more than one row and have an explanation should IMHO be in a method of its own. For example:

```
// generate a flat list of counters
  let counters = data.reduce((a...
```

should be refactored to

```
// 
  let counters = generateFlatListOfCounters(data);
```

It's nicer code of you explain through variable and method names rather than using comments. If you do any changed in the future, people tends to forget to update comments, but—if it's part of the code—programmers are more include to update the names.

---

You shouldn't use setInterval when it comes to timers. Setinterval/settimeout are just "somewhere after X milliseconds". If you want to truly be accurate, you need to read up on [requestanimationframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which updates every time the window repaints.

```js
// data is an array of objects, each representing one of your categories.
// Each category has a .title to store its title and a .counters that
// stores an object for each counter in that category.
var data = [
    {
  title: 'LEAGUES',
  counters: [
    // Each counter has a .title and a .date that is parsed by new Date()
    {
      title: 'IPL',
      date: 'September 19, 2020'
    },
    {
      title: 'BBL',
      date: 'December 3, 2020'
    },
    
  ]
    },
    {
  title: 'ICC TOURNAMENTS',
    counters: [
      {
        title: "Men's T20 World Cup (Postponed)",
        date: "October 18, 2020"
      },
      {
        title: "Women's Cricket World Cup (Postponed)",
        date: 'February 6, 2021'
      },
      
      
    ]
  },
  {
  title: 'INTERNATIONAL SERIES',
     counters: [
      {
        title: "Australia tour of England",
        date: 'September 4, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "West Indies tour of Australia (Postponed)",
        date: 'October 4, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "India tour of Australia",
        date: 'October 11, 2020'
      },
      {
        title: "Afghanistan tour of Australia",
        date: "November 21, 2020"
      },
      {
        title: "New Zealand tour of Australia",
        date: "January 26, 2021"
      },
     
  ]
  },
]
    
  
  // this reduce generates the table
  let table = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc + `<tr><td colspan="6" class="category">${category.title}</td></tr>` +
  category.counters.reduce((acc, counter, index) => {
    return acc + `<tr id="counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}">
    <td>${counter.title}</td>
    <td>${counter.date}</td>
    <td class="days"></td>
    <td class="hours"></td>
    <td class="minutes"></td>
    <td class="seconds"></td>
    </tr>`;
    }, '');
  }, '<tr><th>Event</th><th>Date</th><th>Days</th><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th><th>Seconds</th></tr>');
  
  // REMOVED
  // table += '</table>';
  
  // CHANGED: insert the table after the noscript tag
  // document.getElementById('countdown').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', table);
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = table;
  
  // generate a flat list of counters
  let counters = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc.concat(category.counters.reduce((counterAcc, counter, index) => {
      return counterAcc.concat([{
        // counters will be an array of the objects we generate here.
        // node contains a reference to the tr element for this counter
        node: document.getElementById(`counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}`),
        // date is the date for this counter parsed by Date and then converted
        // into a timestamp
        date: (new Date(counter.date)).getTime()
        }]);
      }, []));
  }, []);
  // calculates time
  const msSecond = 1000,
    msMinute = msSecond * 60,
    msHour = msMinute * 60,
    msDay = msHour * 24;
  let intervalId;
  
  function updateCounters () {
    counters.forEach((counter, counterIndex) => {
    let remaining = counter.date - Date.now(),
      node = counter.node;
    let setText = (selector, text) => node.querySelector(selector).textContent = text;
  
    if (remaining > 0) {
      setText('.days', Math.floor(remaining / msDay));
      remaining %= msDay;
      setText('.hours', Math.floor(remaining / msHour));
      remaining %= msHour;
      setText('.minutes', Math.floor(remaining / msMinute));
      remaining %= msMinute;
      setText('.seconds', Math.floor(remaining / msSecond));
    } else {
      // make sure I don't accidentally display negative numbers if a timer
      // firing late returns a past timestamp (or the data contains a past date)
      setText('.days', 0);
      setText('.hours', 0);
      setText('.minutes', 0);
      setText('.seconds', 0);
  
      // This countdown has reached 0 seconds, stop updating it.
      counters.splice(counterIndex, 1);
      // no more counters? Stop the timer
      if (counters.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
    });
  }
  // display counters right away without waiting a second
  updateCounters();
  intervalId = setInterval(updateCounters, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    
    /* ADDED */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}
div.cricket-ball
{
    text-align: right;
    contain: content;
}
link
{
    color: white;
}
div.calendar-download{
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 25px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      
      a:hover, a:active {
        background-color: red;
      }
/*script {
    display: none;
}*/

content { /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

content > * { /* NEW */
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf;
}
.category {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
td, th {
    padding: .5em;
}
.days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
    text-align: right;
}
#countdown thead tr
{
    background-color: crimson;
}
#image
{
   text-align: right; 
   object-fit: cover;
   padding: 0px;
}
a.twitter-timeline
{
    text-align: right;
    height: fit-content;
}
.twitter  {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /*right: 100px; */
    
    /* NEW */
    text-align: right;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
/*.table {
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
}*/
footer
{
    display: flexbox;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
a
{
    display: inline-block;
}
img.w3-schools
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 175px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CCC</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cccstyle.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+De+Haviland&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--top of the page title--> 
        <header>
            <h1>The CCC</h1>
            <h3>Comprehensive Cricket Countdown</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="calendar-download"> <!--this is the calendar download button which downloads the .ics file-->
            <a href="C:\Users\lukef\Desktop\Website\Comprehensive Cricket Countdown\media\Comprehensive_Cricket_Countdown.ics" download>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IFtJfeb.png" alt="Add to calendar" height="30" width="150">
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <noscript>Sorry, you need JavaScript enabled to view the count
            downs</noscript>

        <content id="content">
          <table class="countdown" id="countdown">
          </table>
          
          <div class="table"></div>
          <script src="table.js"></script>
          <!--This is the link to the javascript that powers the countdown table-->
        
          <div class="twitter" align = "right">
      <!--This is the twitter timeline aligned to the right of the website-->
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="400" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/ICC?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by ICC</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
          </div>
        </content>
<!--    <br> -->
    <footer>
        <!--red background saying thank-you to these websites that helped me with clickable icons-->
      <h1>Special thanks to:</h1>
      <p>
        <a href="https://www.cricbuzz.com" target="blank">
        <img border="0" alt="CricBuzz" src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="151" height="85">
        </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="https://w3schools.com" target="blank">
            <img class="w3-schools" border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i-ij7KM2pFUUpFE31QAUDXg5mzGFNbm16S4tjmg2ZyuhCGLgNJ8oXJRbq7ysh6LoZg" width="100" height="100">
            </a>
        </p>
    </footer>
    
    </body>
</html>
```